# Sublime Text is asking to purchase license. Any suggestions?

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

In each of Mavensmate session i got atleast one alert regarding purchase of Sublime Text license. But this was not the issue with Eclipse IDE. Why Salesforce makes such a dependency to depend on another third party tool which is a paid one. Can Salesforce make life easier just by releasing their own product or atleast some open source which is out of these constraints? Any suggestions please.

[image]

Comment: Buy the license? Sublime Text is nothing to do with Salesforce. It's about $50 from memory.

Comment: You're complaining about purchasing one of the best text editors on the market from a private company, because you happen to use a free and open source plugin associated with it? What exactly is the question here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Sublime Text editor.

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 7):

Neither Sublime Text nor MavensMate are Salesforce products, they are simply third party products that work with the Salesforce platform.

If you want to use the features provided Sublime Text, then support the developers and buy a license ([details here](https://www.sublimetext.com/buy)).

If you don't want to buy a licence then I suggest you switch to another tool, such as the [Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) (Eclipse plug-in), which is provided by Salesforce and is free to use.

Answer (score 3):

The newest version of MavensMate will be available for Github Atom, which is free and open source. You might check that out and stay abreast of the release timeline:

https://atom.io/

https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Atom

Comment: Good to know, but https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Atom just shows "coming soon..." right now.